# How to disable past days and weekends in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

Does anybody know why this Script not working? I am trying to disable weekends and previous dates? I have tried searching all over the web but I am struggling.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="date" class="form-control">

<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {
         $( "#date" ).datepicker({
         beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
         minDate : 'now'
      });
     });
 </script>
```

[DatePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D43sw.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, you simply need to disable the days of the week by utilizing numbers `0-6`. Sunday starting at `0` and Saturday ending at `6`, and obviously, every other day of the week assigned accordingly.  Also, the format of `daysOfWeekDisabled` is a comma delimited string which you will see below. In order to only show today's date and on, simply set a `minDate` of today's date.  All of the above is implemented in code below:

```
let dateToday = new Date(); 

 $('#date').datepicker({
            daysOfWeekDisabled: '0, 6',
            minDate: dateToday
        })
```

Comment: Instead of passing `Date` you can use inbuilt value e.g.  minDate : 'now'

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the problem is you have input type as `date` but if you change that to `test` it will work.

**Working Example:**

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#date").datepicker({
                beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                minDate : 'now'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="date" />
</body>
</html>
```